# MySQL query to create summary row for query with HAVING and LIMIT clauses

Tags: mysql

I'm having issues figuring out how to write a MySQL query that can create a summary row for queries that use HAVING and LIMIT clauses. Here is some sample data and such to recreate my issue..

Sample Table

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `logins` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Sample Data

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `logins`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1,1,'2016-09-25'),
    (2,1,'2016-09-25'),
    (3,2,'2016-09-26'),
    (4,2,'2016-09-26'),
    (5,3,'2016-09-27'),
    (6,3,'2016-09-27'),
    (7,4,'2016-09-28'),
    (8,4,'2016-09-28'),
    (9,5,'2016-09-29'),
    (10,5,'2016-09-29');
```

And here is a my base query showing full results.

```
mysql> select `date`, sum(`logins`) `logins` from `user` group by `date`;
+------------+--------+
| date       | logins |
+------------+--------+
| 2016-09-25 |      2 |
| 2016-09-26 |      4 |
| 2016-09-27 |      6 |
| 2016-09-28 |      8 |
| 2016-09-29 |     10 |
+------------+--------+
```

No problem to get a summary row off of that though right..

```
mysql> select sum(`logins`) `logins` from `user`;
+--------+
| logins |
+--------+
|     30 |
+--------+
```

But what if I wanted to build a summary row out of something like the query below? In this example I've added the HAVING and LIMIT clauses which is meant to simulate a very large data set. The HAVING clause in this query represents what a user could alter as a max amount within filters provided the them in the interface. Limit 0,2 represents page 1 of the results (out of 3 in this case: 0,2; 2,4; 4,6). These queries are part of a paging system used to display results by X,X amount at a time. Thus the reason for the LIMIT clause in the query..

```
mysql> select `date`, sum(`logins`) `logins` from `user` group by `date` having `logins` <= 8 limit 0, 2;
+------------+--------+
| date       | logins |
+------------+--------+
| 2016-09-25 |      2 |
| 2016-09-26 |      4 |
+------------+--------+
```

The summary query that I'm needing for the above result set should tally up 6 logins in this case. How would I go about building a query to do something like this?

Now I cannot simply loop query results (client or server side) to tally up totals because the html table (server side generated) only displays the first page of results and that would only tally up counts displayed on that particular page. I am needing to display a summary row with counts of the full data set across all pages of table pagination, if that makes any sense..

**UPDATE**

Here is a sort of sample of the desired result..

```
+------------+--------+
| date       | logins |
+------------+--------+
| 2016-09-25 |      2 |
| 2016-09-26 |      4 |
+------------+--------+
| TOTAL      |     20 | <-- JUST NEED A QUERY TO PRODUCE THIS NUMBER SOME HOW..
+------------+--------+
```

I'm sorry guys.. I meant to say 20 should be the number, not 6.. Becuase the full result set with the HAVING filter would be so:

```
mysql> select `date`, sum(`logins`) `logins` from `user` group by `date` having `logins` <= 8;
+------------+--------+
| date       | logins |
+------------+--------+
| 2016-09-25 |      2 |
| 2016-09-26 |      4 |
| 2016-09-27 |      6 |
| 2016-09-28 |      8 |
+------------+--------+
```

SORRY!

It's almost like I need a query like so (no group by):

```
select `date`, sum(`logins`) `logins` from `user` having `logins` <= 8
```

But obviously that does not work..

**FINAL UPDATE**

Well here's my 20 based off of @Shadow's answer below which is a very simple example but eventually led me to the answer I needed:

```
mysql> select sum(`logins`) `logins` from (select `date`, sum(`logins`) `logins` from `user` group by `date` having `logins` <= 8) t;
+--------+
| logins |
+--------+
|     20 |
+--------+
```

Comment: that looks suspiciously like what you wanted! Can you show the desired output

Comment: I need a query to show 6 logins as a summary row for that last query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the summing up after the having and limit clauses are applied. Either do this in the presentation layer when you display the numbers or you have to have the 2nd query as a subquery in sql and do the sum in the outer query.

```
select sum(logins) as logins from
    (select `date`, sum(`logins`) `logins` from `user` group by `date` having `logins` <= 8 limit 0, 2) t
```

Comment: Hey now.. This might be exactly what I'm looking for! I remove the limit and am getting what I need (20). Gonna try it out and see.

Comment: Well I got it to work decently based off this answer so thank you very much @Shadow!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to include total results to your query:

```
select u.`date`, 
       sum(u.`logins`) `logins`,
       t.`total_logins` 
from `user` as u  
cross join (select sum(`logins`) `total_logins` from `user`) as t
group by u.`date` 
having `logins` <= 8 limit 0, 2;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/214d9/2)

**Edit:**

You can use the somewhat more complicated query below in order to get the desired result:

```
select `date`, `logins`
from (
  select `date`, `logins`, @rn := @rn + 1  as rn
  from (
     select case when `date` is null then 'Total' else `date` end as `date`, 
            sum(`logins`) as `logins`
     from (
        select `date`, sum(`logins`) `logins` 
        from `user` 
        group by `date` 
        having `logins` <= 8) as t
     group by `date` with rollup ) as s
  cross join (select @rn := 0) as v       
  order by case when `date` = 'Total' then 1 else 0 end,
           `date`) as x
where x.rn <= 2 or x.`date` = 'Total'
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/214d9/21)

Comment: There are only 6 though in the results of that last query above.. This query gives me 30..

Comment: @Rick You state: *I am needing to display a summary row with counts of the full data set* So you need to display the *total* row count?

Comment: "The summary query that I'm needing for the above result set should tally up 6 logins in this case. How would I go about building a query to do something like this?"

Comment: I've done a couple updates above.. I was mistaken on the 6. It should be 20.

Comment: @Giorgos Well that does work just fine but it's a bit overly complicated for my script as the queries are dynamically built and have many filters and many tables that can be joined and such.. But thank you very much for the suggestions!